# Plus signs in UILabel text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, uilabel

I have an iPhone app that uses core.data as its storage and a rest api (apache jersey based).

it retrieves data, saves it to core.data and then displays the data on the app.

The problem i have is that the spaces are replaced with + signs...

Is this an encoding issue that comes from the rest service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that string has been URL Encoded.  Spaces are replaced with + signs. Non alpha numeric characters are replaced by their ASCII equivalents.

I believe you want to decode it using

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```